# Blurred images with Canon 1100D

Tags: canon, blur, canon-1100d

I have a Canon 1100D which I bought last year. The Image quality used to be good. Recently I have noticed that the images are fairly blurred. Even if I use short shutter, stable base for the camera and even after using timer to avoid human error, the output images are blurred and not clear.

Is there any camera settings that I need to calibrate? The blurry images are very annoying.

Comment: Can you post a sample image?  Most often, micro focus adjustments need to be made, which I don't think are possible on the T3 (1100D) but there may be other issues depending on what is actually going on, but without a sample image, there is no way to tell.  Also, can you get a satisfactory result with manual focus?

Comment: could be a lens issue, can you test using a different lens?

Comment: Tech support guys have to ask the embarrassing questions: the lens switch for auto/manual focus is not set to manual is it?

Comment: Worth checking if Image Stabilization was accidentally turned off too.

Comment: @MattGrum: I haven't got a chance to change the lens and check as I have started facing this issue lately. Will give it a try and see if there is any improvement

Comment: @AJHenderson: I will upload a photo soon

Comment: @PatrickHurley: Yes, The camera focus settings is set to Automatic. However I have a shot to both the setting, yielding the same results

Comment: @Gapton: Yup, it was ON the whole time.. but still clueless what might give me the shaky image :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a lot comes to mind on the camera body side, but several things may result in blurry/out of focus photos on the lens side of this problem.

- Auto-focus switch set to On?
- Image stabilizing switch set to On?
- Image stabilizing malfunction?
- Smudges/dirt on the front element of the lens?
- Smudges/dirt on the rear element of the lens?
- Auto-focus malfunction? Stuck focus ring?
- Fungus growth inside lens?
- Moisture condensated inside lens?
- Internal misalignment of lens elements after a hit/bumb?

To test some of these, first check and clean both ends of the lens, set camera to Manual focus, Image stabilizer Off, small aperture (f/16-f/22), fast shutter speed (1/250 sec or faster) and place the camera on steady surface or a tripod, carefully focus manually as best you can, use 10 second timer and shoot a photo of a contrasty subject in such good lighting that ISO will not raise too high (

If the result is still blurred, try another lens.