# How to fix blurry pictures taken with sony digital camera

Tags: sony, blur

I have some pictures taken with my sony digital camera.They are blurry,Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Can you post some examples? And would also be nice to see what settings you have been taking the photos on. For example Focal length, ISO, Aperture and Shutter speed. Without these information and/or examples there is impossible to answer this question. In addition can you take a look at this question: [Blurred images with Canon 1100D](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43162/blurred-images-with-canon-1100d)

Comment: Do you mean fix the pictures that you have already taken? or stop future pictures from being blurry?

Comment: Depending on the blur, there actually [may be some things you can do](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/37697/how-can-i-fix-an-out-of-focus-blurred-photo-in-photoshop/), but it will depend on the exact situation. Please, as previously requested, expand your question with more detail. Additionally, if you have samples to post, that really will help us understand what you need.

Comment: I mean to my previous pics
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_KoexKw4hNCUWNhVzlPQmRCNWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, you can not invent new detail in post production.  If it is very slightly blurry, sharpening can make it look a little better by making edges stronger, but there isn't any actual gain in detail.  Whatever level of detail you have is the level of detail you will get.  Post production tools don't have anywhere to get what the information should have been for those pixels, so it can only work with what it has.

Answer (score 4):

No.

It is impossible to "fix" blur (I assume this is caused by a slow shutter and camera shake in your case).
If it is very, very, very slight blur, applying "Sharpening" may help a little but otherwise, no.

Answer (score 3):

It will be nearly impossible to completely fix blurred pics in post.

If you are concerned about avoiding this in the future, you need to figure out why they were blurry.  Was it low light and the camera speed was too slow for hand holding?  Were you not appropriately steady when you shot it?

Or are all pics from this camera blurry? In which case, it needs service.